# Exclude sheets from list Of Sheet Names With Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have found this piece of script that can create a list of all the sheet names in a Google sheet using app script.

But i would like to exclude some of the sheets from the list. For example if i don't want "Sheet 2" and "Sheet 4" in the list

```
function sheetnames() { 
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out  
}
```

Comment: Make an effort, please. It's just an `if` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Excluded selected sheets

```
function sheetnames() { 
  var out = new Array()
  var exA = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"];
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().filter(sh => !~exA.indexOf(sh.getName()));
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sheetNames() {

  const exclude = [`Sheet1`, `Sheet2`]

  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                       .getSheets()
                       .map(sheet => sheet.getName())
                       .filter(sheet => !exclude.includes(sheet))

}
```